# How to determine which drop-down is changed from a number of selects sharing same name as an array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a number of dropdowns (like dozens) arranged in rows in a table with same name and square brackets (objects[]) so that I can have their values as an array when posted.

```
<tr 1>
  <select  name="objects[]">
     <option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>
     <option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>

  </select>
</tr>

<tr 2>
  <select  name="objects[]">
     <option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>
     <option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>

  </select>
</tr>
```

**Question**
When I change the value of a drop-down, using jquery/js is it possible to uniquely identify which drop-down's value is changed from this set of drop-downs? i.e to get the index of the drop-down.

**Use Case** is to populate a text field next to the changed drop-down in the same row and as they all share the same name with [] I want to identify which one is changed to update text field at the correct place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get the index of the element, we can watch for change using the `.on()` function, we attach it to all the `select` elements, then we get the value using `.val()` and set the same to the adjacent `input` we find using `.next` function.

```js
//optional code - for initalization
$('select').each(function(){
  $(this).next( "input" ).val($(this).val());
});
//optional code - for initalization

$('select').on("change", function(){
$(this).next( "input" ).val($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr 1>
  <select  name="objects[]">
     <option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>
     <option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>

  </select>
  <input type="text"/> 
</tr>

<tr 2>
  <select  name="objects[]">
     <option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>
     <option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>

  </select>
  <input type="text"/> 
</tr>
```